# Issue getting username of currently locked session (Microsoft account vs local) in Windows 10 Credential Provider

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unlock, credential-providers

I'm developing a Windows 10 credential provider which acts only at the unlock scenario (of a currently signed in user). As described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762493(v=vs.85).aspx), starting from Windows 10, the CPUS_LOGON and CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION user scenarios have been combined. Credential providers that need to enumerate the currently user logged into the system can keep track of the current user or leverage APIs such as WTSQuerySessionInformation to obtain that information.

Using [WTSQuerySessionInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(v=vs.85).aspx), I can get the username of the currently logged in user (WTSUserName). At login, the system calls [ICredentialProviderSetUserArray::SetUserArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706921(v=vs.85).aspx) during the initialization of the login UI to retrieve the set of users to show in the UI. Credential provider users ([ICredentialProviderUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706922(v=vs.85).aspx)) can be retrieved from the [ICredentialProviderUserArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706923(v=vs.85).aspx) interface and for each user we can query the username (by querying the string value [PKEY_Identity_UserName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706930(v=vs.85).aspx)). Comparing the username from WTSQuerySessionInformation and the one returned by PKEY_Identity_UserName allows me to know which user is the last currently locked user. (There could be multiple accounts with [PKEY_Identity_LogonStatusString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706930(v=vs.85).aspx) set to "Locked").

This works well for local accounts which are not signed in with a Microsoft Account. For the ones signed in as Microsoft Account, the username returned by WTSQuerySessionInformation differs from the one given by PKEY_Identity_UserName.

For user signed in as "my_user_microsoft@myemail.com", I got the following mismatch.

- Using WTSQuerySessionInformation, I get as username of currently locked user:

  Username: my_us
- And the one returned by PKEY_Identity_UserName is well:

  Username: my_user_microsoft@myemail.com

  Qualified Username: MicrosoftAccount\my_user_microsoft@myemail.com

The username returned by the WTSQuerySessionInformation is truncated and don't report the full email address and thus don't allow me to compare to the other usernames while enumerating the users.

Any idea why the username is cropped this way? Is there a way to get the full username using WTSQuerySessionInformation?
This behaviour has been tested on a freshly created Microsoft Account.

Comment: How you retrieve user names? The problem might be with situation and how you use that function. WTS_CURRENT_SESSION  may get inconsistent. Why you're not using SIDs to compare?

Comment: @Swift: Comparing the SID did the trick. Thanks!! I posted the answer how to get the SID of the locked user from username and domain.

Comment: @skuallpa I'm working on a custom credential provider using V2 where setUserArray() returns only local accounts. May I know how you are getting the domain and azure account in setUserArray()? is there a way to get?

Comment: I am working on a Windows 10 Cred Provider, and I am having trouble with the CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION scenario. My CP simply serializes a Username and Password and logs the user in. This works in the CPUS_LOGON scenario, but I get a bad username and password in the CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION scenario. I am thinking I need to "...enumerate the currently user logged into the system..." and set that user as the default credential, but I don't know how. Your question helps, but how exactly do I set the default credential once I find it in ICredentialProviderUserArray?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by comparing the SID rather than the username and domain. The SID can be retrieved using [LookupAccountName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159(v=vs.85).aspx) with the username and domain of the currently locked user (query WTSUserName and WTSDomainName with [WTSQuerySessionInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(v=vs.85).aspx)). [This example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707085(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_1) from Microsoft was very helpful.

Then while looping through the credential provider users (in the [ICredentialProviderSetUserArray::SetUserArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706921(v=vs.85).aspx) function), I could detect which one is the currently locked user. Thanks @Swift to point me on the solution.

Comment: Hello, i am trying to develop a c# credential provider as well. I can log user in but i cannot unlock workstation. It always give Incorrect username or password. Where should i call WtsQuerySessionInformation and how do i use it? Thanks.